# Android to disable a textview, meanwhile having its drawables enabled

Tags: android, textview, drawable

I would like to know whether it is possible to keep a textview disabled but to have its drawable components in a enabled mode. Thanks

Comment: What exactly would not be enabled then? There is only so much a textview can do

Comment: What you mean by disabling text view, It doesn't make any sense. If you want to show it as disabled then you can use some lighter text colour. Like if others are black then you can make it Gray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is not posssible. For doing this you need to take textview and imageview separately

Answer (score 0):

Set the text to "" so that text wont be displayed but the drawables will still be visible. For example

```
txtView.setText("");
```

P.S : I couldn't comment as I need more reputation.